# git push hangs... could be ssh config related

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I'm happy to close this issue if there's a duplicate with a viable solution, but somewhere in the last few months, I'm stuck with `git push` hanging on Mac 10.15.7 (not sure if that's related). This doesn't seem to be based on Github or Gitlab, etc. I think it has something to do with SSH itself.

```sh
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/{username}/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 47: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com port 22.
```

At one point, I killed `ssh-agent` from "Activity Monitor" and I was able to push once, but since then, it's been recurring with no instances of `ssh-agent` or `ssh` even appearing in "Activity Monitor".

Answer (score 1):

I hate answering my own questions, but I looked for a solution to this for a few days. Turns out, using `netcat` as the SSH proxy command helped resolve my issue.

Edit (or create) `~/.ssh/config` with the following:

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand nc %h %p
```

**Note:** I wouldn't put this in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, as it may get overwritten or something after an OS update.

Answer (score 0):

Try, for testing, using a PEM SSH key (register the public key), without passphrase (just to check if SSH itself is broken)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -P "" -f ~/.ssh/testKey
# register testKey.pub to your GitLab profile
ssh -Tv -i ~/.ssh/testKey ssh://git@gitlab.com
```

If you see a welcome message, try and export GIT_SSH='ssh -i  ~/.ssh/testKey', then try your `git push` again.

Comment: Same thing... hangs with the same output =/

Comment: @daleyjem can you check if `ssh -4 -Tv -i ...` works better? (as in https://mjtsai.com/blog/2020/03/31/macos-10-15-4-broke-ssh/#comment-3192977)

Comment: That didn't work, but instead I used a different recommendation on that URL you sent. I added `ProxyCommand nc %h %p` to my `~/.ssh/config` file.